# SQL Server - Why doesn't column show full string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with the following column:

```
Column Name|Data Type    |Allow Nulls
FullName   |nvarchar(250)|Yes
```

When I try to insert a new Full Name longer then 10 characters it cuts off anything after the 10 characters.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO ..(FullName)
VALUES ('Apple EnPearSSSS')
```

Results in the database:

```
FullName   |
Apple EnPe |
```

Expected Results:

```
FullName         |
Apple EnPearSSSS |
```

Why is the column limit to 10 characters?

Actual results after adding alias for the selected field:

```
  FULLNAME                    .|
1|Apple EnPe                   |
2|Test vriri                   |
3|new   lfll                   |
4|abcdefghij                   |
```

Solution:
The issue here is to insert the FullName there is a stored procedure with @FullName limited to nvarchar10. So any inserts done through the stored procedure, was truncating because of the datatype limit set on the stored procedure, not the table. If I insert anything without using the stored procedure, it works as intended.

Comment: Are you using Management Studio? You may just need to resize the column in order to fit the full string.

Comment: Yes I am, may you please clarify what you mean by resize the column?

Comment: You can drag the columns in the grid to see more of each cell.  Same as expanding columns in Excel, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still limited to 10 characters, the arSSSS does not appear in the column. Only, Apple EnPe.

Comment: It seems a bug in SSMS 2008. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/356926/ssms-grid-alignment-column-width-seems-arbitrary

Comment: are you directly doing that query in the sql? or you're doing it using Stored procedure and declaring parameters?

Comment: If I perform the insert through the stored procedure, it gets limited because the stored procedure parameter @FullName is set to nvarchar10. Where as if you insert using the query in sql it inserts as intended. The issue was everything in the database used the stored procedure to insert, which is why all the values was limited to 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to alias the selected field

```
SELECT FullName as [FullName               .] FROM YourTable
```

The alias will expand the column width.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work, still get the limit on the column. From the link provided above there is no workarounds - just update to newer SSMS. Is there anything else you can think of that might work?

Comment: Can you do a screen capture and show us what smss 2008 is showing with the query above?

Comment: Added to question under Actual Result: the | is where the column stops.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a problem in your data type length, as a result the string got truncated when it's inserted.

Comment: data type length testing: NVARCHAR(250), NVARCHAR(50), NVARCHAR(MAX),  NVARCHAR(10),  VARCHAR(250) gets the same result.

Comment: Interesting, can you also provide the full table schema and query used for `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the datatype of your column to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: VARCHAR datatype didn't work, I didn't release there was a stored procedure causing the insert to truncate.

Comment: Well I suggest if you will not use unicode characters, you change your datatype to VARCHAR. NVARCHAR takes up 2bytes per character in your memory while VARCHAR only takes up 1byte per character.